# How to know if javac compiled cleanly using system() in python

Tags: java, python

In python, how can I tell if a certain system() call is successful? In the program I am writing I need to know if a java program compiled correctly using javac, which is called using system() (in the python program). So I need to know if javac threw any exceptions, if there were any syntax problems with the java program, any problems at all at compile time for the java program. Essentially, the program asks the user for a dir, then asks for the java program name, then asks if it takes any arguments, then it compiles it with system('javac ' + str(javaFile) + '.java').

Comment: That's a staggeringly naive approach. Use `subprocess` as it will give you any output and the exit code and also won't break on e.g. filenames with spaces if used appropriately (i.e. with a list `['javac', '--some-opt', javafile+'.java']` as `command`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, `os.system` has been deprecated.

An exit code of `0` indicates successful termination, a non-zero exit code means an error occurred.

There are many convenience functions available, let's take an example of `subprocess.call`

```
>>> subprocess.call(['ls', '-a'])
0
```

Successful, as `ls` was called with correct arguments.

Now let's try:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['ls', '-T'])   # option -T requires an argument
2
```

Invalid arguments and it returns `2`.

If `javac` did compile successfully, it should return `0`. Otherwise, an error is thrown. This depends on which function of the `subprocess` module is called.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, os.system returns the exit status of the started process. It does not work the same way on Windows.

os.system is intended to be replaced by the module subprocess from Python 2.4.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess